# How to integrate Snipcart api key securely in React

Tags: reactjs, security, api-key, aws-secrets-manager, snipcart

I want to create an online store using React and Snipcart. Seems the main security concern with this approach is storing my Snipcart secret api key. I want to know the most secure way to store this. I just found out that using a .env file in React to store this is not secure as it is embedded into the build and anyone could potentially view this. I am wondering if anyone has stored API keys using something like AWS Secrets Manager? I have been looking into this approach and wondering if I could store my secret key in secrets manager and then just invoke it with a Lambda function or something. If I were to have my React app make a request to receive the API key, could someone using the network tab in dev tools possibly intercept this request and view my API secret key?

Another way I have considered is building a backend that communicates with snipcart separately that my React app could just call, but I would prefer not to do this approach as this would add a considerable amount of cost.

Here is a link to [basic installation](https://docs.snipcart.com/v3/setup/installation) on snipcart docs, seems the api key needs to go into a script tag - couldn't someone see this potentially?

Here is their reference to [authentication](https://docs.snipcart.com/v3/api-reference/authentication) in their docs as well.

Answer (score 0):

You put the public API key in the script. It doesn't matter that others have access to it. The private keys are of other API requests, if you would create a dashboard or something to view your data other ways than the official dashboard. Those keys are needed to be kept secret.